# Появление и скрытие элемента при скроллинге

Tags: jquery, css

Использую простейший код для появления элемента при скроллинге

```
jQuery(function(f){
var element = f('#name');
f(window).scroll(function(){
    element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 200 ? 'In': 'Out')](500);           
});
});
```

Стили по умолчанию:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: %;
height: ;
background: ;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 99999;
display: none;
```

Вроде все ок, но при закрытии элемента при дальнейшем скроллинге элемент всплывает вновь. Можно ли как-то запретить появление элемента после его закрытия?

Comment: Используйте плагин reveal js :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ссылку на функцию при прикреплении обработчика, чтобы потом можно было его снять:

```
function revealElem() {
    ...

    //тут же вы снимаете обработчик:
    f(window).off('scroll', revealElem)
}

f(window).on('scroll', revealElem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно, просто задайте переменную например `isAlreadyShow`:

```
let isAlreadyShow = false;
```

В момент как только элемент всплывает:

```
isAlreadyShow = true;
```

И условиe:

```
if(!isAlreadyShow) {
   // show element function
}
```

Comment: Ребята, спасибо, почему-то рейтинг повысить не могу.

Comment: Почему?:) стрелочку вверх или галочку нажимаешь и все:)